# How to derive magnetic moment for integrated circuit level?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

Imagine we have a circuit on the xy-plane, with a random geometry (it just need to be closed). I want to calculate the magnetic moment of this setup:

$$\vec{m} = \frac{1}{2} \int_V d^3 x' \vec{x}' \times \vec{j}(\vec{x}')$$

Assuming that current is constant we get $I d \vec{x}' = \vec{j}(\vec{x}')$ which turns the integral into:

$$\vec{m} = \frac{1}{2} \int_V d^3 x' \vec{x}' \times (I d\vec{x}')$$

Next step in the computation, I'm trying to follow, is immediately writing down: 
$$\vec{m} = \frac{1}{2} I \int_{\delta A} \vec{x}' \times d\vec{x}'$$

I probably flunked an important lesson and can't understand what is happening here. We don't use Stokes, because then the "$\times$" would go away.

My question is: **how does the integral over the volume/surface transform into one over its edge?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider [Ostrogradsky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem):

$\iiint_V\left[\mathbf{G}\cdot\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\right) - \mathbf{F}\cdot \left( \nabla\times\mathbf{G}\right)\right]\, dV  = \underbrace{\oint\oint}_\textrm{Surface} \mathbf F\times\mathbf{G}\cdot d\mathbf{S}.$

which is special case of the Stokes' theorem, but saves cross-product.

Comment: @user17574 Is this question still actual? Maybe, you found other solution?